# Refining this name parse pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-negation

This pattern

```
/^(.*?)\b((?:[Vv][ao]n|(?:[Dd][eu]\s+)?[Ll]a|[Dd][eu]|St\.|Le|Auf\s+der)\s+\p{L}+\.?)(.*)/gum
```

parses name tokens.

I had help deriving this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/itc2ir/3) (ECMAScript Flavor) and have made small adjustments, but I'm stuck on the third name token in the test string.

`Van H. Manning` properly parses to `Van H.`  `Manning` (just use `trim()` to remove extra space)

`Lionel Van Deerlin` properly parses to `Lionel` `Van Deerlin`

But `Van Taylor` does not parse to `Van` `Taylor`

Can this pattern be adjusted to properly parse `Van Taylor` along with the other instances of `Van`?

I'm still working out how this pattern works and how to understand this particular regex wizardry.

TIA

** Update **

Fools errand though it may be, I am doing the best possible version of a parse.

Per the comments, `Van H. Manning` is distinct because `Van` is a first name whereas `Van Deerlin` is a surname.

Similarly to `Van H. Manning`, `Van Taylor` consists of `Van` as a first name and `Taylor` as a surname.

I can see that part of the logic is that `Van` ocurring at the beginning of the string distinguishes between surname and last name, however, the pattern is properly grouping `Van \w+` already so it seems like a small adjustment is needed.

As far as `Van H. Manning` being parsed as `Van H.`  `Manning`, I am using a conditional to handle that. It's beyond me on how to regex that one with everything else and I've already asked for a lot of heavy lifting here.

Comment: Change the first `.*?` to `.+?` so the first name can't be empty.

Comment: That helps, but other changes are needed as well. Some of them cause `H.` to move to the surname. Using regular expressions to parse names is a fools errand, there are too many variations.

Comment: The main issue is to understand why you want to handle `van` differently in `Van H. Manning`, `Lionel Van Deerlin` and `Van Taylor`. We need to know the exact difference, what the conditions are to place `Van` in Group 2 and the next word into Group 3 and when to put all in Group 2.
`

Comment: @barmar changing `.*?` to `.+?` excludes `Van H. Manning` completely, as well as a couple of others. Maybe this is the best I can get.

Comment: As I said above, other changes end up being needed. It's going to end up being a total mess because regexp isn't the appropriate tool for this.

Comment: What tool do you recommend @barmar?

Comment: Maybe there's something in a NLP library. Why do you need to do this in the first place? If it's an input form, use separate fields for first and last names.

Comment: That's a good question @Wiktor. I guess I should figure that out first.

Comment: It's not a web form. I'm processing a huge list of names. An NLP library seems like way more of a trip down a rabbit hole than just figuring out how to parse this. I have no experience with NLP, so that means then going on to studying NLP. It's cool if you don't have an answer. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of names that you want to split into given name(s) and surname(s). This practically impossible without making many assumptions about the structure of the names (some cultures put surnames before given names, some cultures use multiple surnames). Your regex seems to be focused on handling common European name structures with given name(s) before a single surname (which may include a common prefix separated from the surname by whitespace).

Comment: I don't understand the `\p{L}+` part of the regular expression in this question.

Comment: I found reference to `\p{}` as matching a Unicode code point class (in this case any Unicode letter code point).

Comment: Your understanding of the input is correct @robartsd. Also, the unicode accounts for names with diacriticals. I didn't know about this. The person who helped improve the pattern added that piece for me.

Comment: `\p{L]` will match any letter code point, but it will fail to match diacritical that consist of a letter code point followed by a combining mark code point.

Comment: I could also see possible trouble if names contain seniority terms (Jr., Sr., I, II, III, IV, ...) at the end.

Comment: I accounted for the suffix issue in a conditional. This pattern covers the remainder after the Jr, Sr is stripped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will get rather complicated to handle all cases because
as everybody pointed out, you'll probably get the first name in front
or behind the surname (last name or family name). In some countries I
even think that your last name can come from your parent's first name,
so imagine how complicated it can get to try and detect the order.

But, if you want to stick to a regular expression, you could just use
your assumption that if `Van` is at the beginning of the string then
it's the first name. In this case, just add two alternatives to your
regular expression and capture the parts in several groups. I've
named them for easier access, compared to indexed groups. You'll then
have to put some logic to see which group is filled or empty.

I also used the `i` flag for case-**i**nsensitive instead of handling
it with `[Dd]`.

I personally think that having several regular expressions or trying to
find a library to handle that for you might be a better idea, especially
if you also know the origin of the person, which could help to use
specific rules by region of the planet.

The *PCRE* regex :

```
/^
(?: # Where "Van" would be the first name:
  (?<firstname_van>Van)\s(?<lastname_van>.*)
|
  # Other cases: the first name is probably first, but not sure.
  (?<firstname>.*?)\s*
  (?<lastname>
    \b
    (?:
      (?<!^)V[ao]n
      |(?:D[eu]\s+)?La
      |D[eu]
      |St\.
      |Le
      |Auf\s+der
    )
    \s+\p{L}+\.?
  )
  \h*
  (?:
    (?<senority>(?:[JS]r\.?|[IVX]+))
    |
    (?<more>.*)
  )
)
$/gumix
```

The *JavaScript* version to enhance :

```js
const regexp = /^(?:(?<firstname_van>Van)\s(?<lastname_van>.*)|(?<firstname>.*?)\s*(?<lastname>\b(?:(?<!^)V[ao]n|(?:D[eu]\s+)?La|D[eu]|St\.|Le|Auf\s+der)\s+\p{L}+\.?)[ \t]*(?:(?<senority>(?:[JS]r\.?|[IVX]+))|(?<more>.*)))$/gumi;

const input = `Van H. Manning 
Lionel Van Deerlin
Van Taylor
Emile La Sére
George A. La Dow
Gilbert De La Matyr
Robert M. La Follette
William Leroy La Follette
Robert M. La Follette Sr.
Robert M. La Follette Jr.
Charles M. La Follette
Monica De La Cruz
David A. De Armond
Justin De Witt Bowersock
De Witt C. Giddings
Julien de Lallande Poydras
Henry St. John
Edward St. Loe Livermore
Oscar L. Auf der Heide
Kika de la Garza
Francis Celeste Le Blond
Robert Le Roy Livingston`;

let i = 1;
while ((match = regexp.exec(input)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Match ${i++}`, match.groups);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer a solution. I will take a look at it and see what I can do with it.